# PHP @var Documentation pattern

Tags: php, documentation, document

I did read a lot about PHP documentation and how to do the comments inside the classes, but I do not know yet if have any pattern to identify the size of a variable. I didn't saw any convention that talk about this kind of information. What I'm doing a Web Service and some parameters has a required size. Example:

> **What I got:**

```php
/**
 *
 * @access private
 * @var string
 */
private $password;
```

> **What I want:**

```
/**
 *
 * @access private
 * @var string 10 (<-- size)
 */
private $password;
```

What I want to know if I write the size after identifying the type is correct. Or if have any way to do that or if I don't have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres no need to had the size, actually there's nothing regarding the size in [phpdoc](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html)

it should be only

```
/**
 * @var <type> [$<var name>]
 */
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: But I'm worried because I'm working on a very large application that has 30000 php files and I want to be as explicit as possible.

Comment: I would to that on the setter's and/or validators... If you actually want to add the size there, then you probably need to decide some method yourself. I never saw that and don't know an IDE that will actually give any hint on string/int/array size. But leave the question open, there might be someone that actually did that.

Comment: I really appreciate your help @xicoxperto I did the same as your answer. I'll wait one or two days, if I have no clue, I'll close this with your answer.